# Add shell command into vscode command palette

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have pandoc installed on my device. I want to add the pandoc export command so I can create PDF file by compiling that command in one click in vscode command palette (No need to type that long command again and again). Is there a simple way to do it besides creating my own extension?

Comment: You can just create a keybinding for the shell command, you don't even need a task.  That won't put it into your Command Palette though.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [custom task in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks) that executes your pandoc command.
Then use the command palette (*Tasks: Run Task*) to execute it or [create a keyboard binding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_binding-keyboard-shortcuts-to-tasks) for the task.

A task that converts the file currently opened in the editor would look like this:

```json
{
  "label": "Pandoc: Convert current file",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "pandoc '${file}' ...",
  "problemMatcher": []
}
```

Adjust the `"pandoc '${file}' ..."` command as required.

You can also reference other [variables predefined by VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables).

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I apply this globally? So I can do this task wherever the directory I work on.

Comment: It is not clear to me, what you _exactly_ mean by "globally". Do you want to convert the very file same no matter what file you are currently editing in your workspace?

Comment: The term "globally" is no matter wherever the `.md` file stored at, vscode can always recognize it and the convert command is available

Comment: I updated my initial answer providing an example. Hope this meets your use case.

Comment: @ct_jdr I strongly suggest putting the file variable in ticks like `'${file}'` to handle cases where there are spaces in the file or folder structure that would otherwise break the command.

Comment: @mark, edited the answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the Command Pallete, search for `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` - there are some similar ones so chose this one specifically.  Then, in the file that it will open - `keybindings.json` - , add the below keybinding.  There will be an outer `[]` surrounding all of the keybindings together.

Then, using whatever keybinding you chose, here <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and focus is in the terminal, it should print out that command.  You will need to hit <kbd>Return/Enter</kbd> to actually run the command.

```
  {
    "key": "alt+b",          // whatever keybinding you wish
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
        "text": "pandoc '${file}' --pdf-engine=xelatex -o example13.pdf"
    },
    "when": "terminalFocus && !terminalTextSelected"
  }
```

Use whatever your `pandoc` command is.  `${file}` is the current file.

You don't really need the `"whwn"` clause if you want to trigger it whether the terminal has focus or not - so you could comment that out if you used a unique `"key"`.  Also, if you want it to run without having to hit the `Enter` after it is printed into your terminal just add a `\u000D` (which is a <kbd>Return</kbd>) to the end like this:

```
"text": "pandoc '${file}' --pdf-engine=xelatex -o example13.pdf\u000D"
```

Comment: Where should I put/write this code block? In which file? Could you please tell me step-by-step to do it or refer to any document?

Comment: I edited the answer to show more where it goes and how to use it.